# How to change machine type in Google Cloud Build and set quota for specific location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am using Google Cloud build. But my setup is getting quite slow.

Im experimenting with using caching, but I also want to try and use a faster machine for my builds.

Therefore I specified the following in my cloudbuilds.yaml file

```
options:
  machineType: "E2_HIGHCPU_32"
```

However, when I try to build I am getting the following error:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: generic::failed_precondition: due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds of this machine type in this region
```

I tried to increase the quota, but cannot figure out which one it is or how its done.

I am using the region europe-west1 for my builds.

Can anybody help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new build trigger or modify the existing trigger and make sure you leave out the region as **"global"** instead of **"europe-west1"** or whatever your specific region is.

Also, go to cloudbuild settings & under the **WORKER POOL** tab create a private pool machine that matches the machine type you specified in your **cloudbuild.yaml** file

Comment: That solved my problems thank you! To make life easier for people finding this I think it is worth mentioning that the possible values for the machineType enum can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/cloudbuild/latest/cloudbuild/protos.google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.buildoptions.machinetype

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to increase your quota, you should go to the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page. There are both global quotas and regional quotas, so you need to update the relevant ones (sometimes both). Instructions for updating quotas is described in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota_detail/view_manage#managing_your_quota_console

You have correctly switched machine type in your YAML file. There is no reason in this case to use a private pool; it only makes it more expensive, so unless you have specific needs that require it or need a different machine type than what is available by default (details [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/pricing)), then just configure it in your options as you've done already.